# Combining polygons that are within another polygon using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have two layers of which one represents the catastres and another one represents the areas of the town that are flooded (represented as risk levels 0-3).

As these two maps are combined the following picture is created:

[image]

Initially, I had manually put a risk level for each catastre, however, this does not accurately represent the level of risk and is fairly tedious to do later on when the same ask shall be repeated for other sites.

Is there a way to assign within the Attribute Table for the layer of catastres a risk level based on the significance of flooding within its boundaries (i.e. if 90% of the total area of catastre is flooded, then the risk level assigned is 3 if 60%-89% of the total area of catastre is flooded then risk level assigned is 2, if 1-59% of the catastre is flooded then risk level is 1, etc.)?

For the "Catastres" I have all of the XY coordinates and the area within the attribute table and for the flood area, I also have all of the XY coordinates and areas. I have so far tried the select by location/attributes/union commands.

Comment: I would start with a workflow like this 1) calculate the cadastre area to a non-esri controlled field.  2) intersect your cadastre and flooding layers.  This will limit cadastre polygons to flooded areas.  The esri shape field will have the flooded area and area field from step 1 will have the total cadastre area for that block 3) calculate a percent and decide rating 4) copy the rating information back to the cadastre layer using a joinfield on your original cadastre id